# How to sum an expression outside of aggregate ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

My current table has a grouping by Client's and the tablix displays all transaction's per each client and Total per client. On the bottom of the tablix I have a grouping to sum each client's Amount but I'm having trouble for the Report Total Suming because it's an expression.

The expression is

```
Total Expression =Last(Fields!Balance.Value, "TransactionDTO")
```

and it grabs the final balance row and sums it instead of summing all transaction rows.

My question is how do I sum that expression? My ReportTotal row, Total column should be something like below but that didn't work.

```
ReportTotal Expression = Sum(Last(Fields!Balance.Value, "TransactionDTO"))
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, is the bottom row summing the total of all Clients together into a single value?

Comment: The final row, Report Total, is summing all the totals of clients together Except I want the empty box at the moment to sum the expression

Comment: @Master Why you are not handling Total(Balance) column same way as amount column? `=SUM([Balance])` If you can provide a sample output it will be easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need code to make it work the way you want.

```
Public Total As Decimal

Function AddTotal(ByVal Money as Decimal) as Decimal
Total = Total + Money
AddTotal = Money
End Function
```

For the detail rows, use

```
=code.AddTotal(Last(Fields!Balance.Value, "TransactionDTO"))
```

The code will track your individual balances and output the same value for the detail.

And for the total,

```
=code.Total
```

Comment: Hi @Hannover Fist this worked perfectly for one page. But when there are separate pages, the values don't sum together. For example, page 1 has a total of 1000, 2000. Page 2 has 4000, the report total row will display only 4000.